# Amazon SNS For Apple - Error loading apple credentials from file

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to create SNS Application for IOS. After uploading the .p12 file and entering the password I clicked on "Load Credentials From File" button, but I always get the following error message:

"Error loading apple credentials from file"

Please, does anybody know what's going on? what's the problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have exported the wrong P12 file.

Open KeyChain Access, click "Certificates" at the left panel, click the arrow at the left hand side of your certificate, there's a private key below. You need to export that key.

Attached a screenshot to better illustrate this.

[image]

Comment: Please mark my answer as Accepted Answer if the solution helps. Thank you.

Comment: you save my day!

Comment: I am trying to create Apple Development platform at AWS SNS with old p12 file. But unable to create. This old p12 file is already used at another AWS SNS.

I am getting error i.e Error loading Apple credentials from file Please help me

Answer (score 4):

If you don't work with Ken Tan's solution,

**Make sure the name of your private key to be in English.**

Some Japanese / Korean users failed to do this because of the name of key in their language. I think this problem could occur in countries not using Roman characters.

**When making CSR, you should use a name in English.**

Comment: You are lifesaver !

Comment: I am trying to create Apple Development platform at AWS SNS with old p12 file. But unable to create. This old p12 file is already used at another AWS SNS.

I am getting error i.e Error loading Apple credentials from file Please help me